# Wave file numerical metadata

Tags: wav

Why is all the numerical metadata not stored as ASCII characters? For example, to find the sampling rate, which starts at byte 24, you have to read four bytes and the perform some endian swaps and bit shifts to get the actual number. Why not just store the sample rate as its ASCII?

Comment: Because computers need it in binary. They would have to convert the ascii back to binary number to get the sampling rate.

Comment: I'm not a programmer (therefore it's just a comment) but I'm pretty certain it's computationally far more expensive to convert a number written in ASCII to an actual integer. Reading few bytes so they can be *directly* interpreted as integer in a programming language seems easier, even if you need to shift or swap some bits or bytes. Commands to shift bits or copy bytes are so *basic* any(?) assembler has them.

Answer (score 2):

For computers, doing the byte swap is much easier than parsing a decimal number. Storing a binary number also takes less disk space.

For example, to read the number 0x12345678 from a buffer:

```
def read32le_binary(buf):
    return buf[0] << 24 | buf[1] << 16 | buf[2] << 8 | buf[3]

def read32_text(buf):
    n = 0
    for i in range(11):
        n = 10 * n + buf[i] - '0'
    return n
```

The first function reads the binary data. It contains 6 arithmetic operations, which is quite fast.

On some computers, when the endianness matches and the CPU allows unaligned memory reads, it takes only 0 arithmetic operations.

On the other hand, the text version takes 48 operations, which is much more. And even worse, the above code is naive. What if the memory contains characters other than digits? That might produce an overflow. Or if the resulting number is larger than what a 32-bit number can represent?

For all these reasons, there are many file formats that make use of binary representation. Text format is often used for file formats that are "closer to humans", like XML for actual text documents.